# Trying to create Sub-type with fields of only a certain type, then get create a type that is the keyof that sub-type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a sub-type (`ST`) of a generic type `I` that enforces that sub-type (`ST`) is an object with a subset of fields from that `I` generic with a certain type `DocumentReference`.

example:

```
type SubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<
  Base,
  { [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never }[keyof Base]
>;

  private joinOnField<
    I,
    J,
    K extends keyof ST,
    ST = SubType<I, DocumentReference>
  >(data: ST, docRefField: K): Observable<J> {
    if (!data[docRefField]) {
      return of(null);
    }

    if ((<DocumentReference>data[docRefField]).get) {
      return of(null);
    }

    return from(data[docRefField].get().then(snap => snap.data() as J));
  }
```

I keep on getting an error saying

> Conversion of type 'ST[K]' to type 'DocumentReference' may be a
>   mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If
>   this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

I thought I was pretty explicit int that ST only has fields of type `DocumentReference`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler can't follow such conditions as long as the conditional type still has such unresolved type parameters (such as inside the generic function).

You should follow the advice of the compiler and use a double assertion `data[docRefField] as unknown as DocumentReference`